# initramfs, what is it and why am I getting this message

Tags: command-line, initramfs

I am new to linux and having trouble getting my head around all of it, so please bear with me.
I am getting this message every time I use: sudo apt-get upgrade

It's a fresh install of Ubuntu which took out dual boot for windows and there are other installs on other drives within the system that I currently can't work out how to access... probably a separate issue.

Message/s:

```
... Setting up linux-firmware (1.173.16) ...  
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-40-generic  
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/sda5  
I: (UUID=8cc84133-bb6c-4c98-999c-28315297dacf)  
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.  
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-28-generic  
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/sda5  
I: (UUID=8cc84133-bb6c-4c98-999c-28315297dacf)  
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.  
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-26-generic  
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/sda5  
I: (UUID=8cc84133-bb6c-4c98-999c-28315297dacf)  
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.  
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-37-generic  
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/sda5  
I: (UUID=8cc84133-bb6c-4c98-999c-28315297dacf)  
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.  
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-23-generic  
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/sda5  
I: (UUID=8cc84133-bb6c-4c98-999c-28315297dacf)  
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
```

I have gleaned from other questions that this has something to do with resuming after a suspend?
I haven't ever put the PC into suspend mode, so I'm not sure why these files(?) have been created.

What should can I do to resolve this?
Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: The I: at the start tells you they are *informational* messages and not errors.  If you haven't hibernated, a save file will not be found, so a single informational message is to be expected (it would be an error only if you did hibernate, and it wasn't found, but the system will still report it as informational as the lack of file is what the system uses to know you didn't hibernate).

Comment: You might also consider removing some old kernels.

Answer (score 0):

Run the next to see your UUIDs:

```
sudo blkid | grep -i swap
```

Create `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` file by:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume
```

Paste there previously taken UUID for your `/dev/sda5`.

For example:

```
$ sudo blkid | grep -i swap
[sudo] password for user: 
/dev/sdb5: UUID="1053a199-0b8f-44ae-9356-c04f5864b138" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="4e24c763-05"
```

UUID is of `TYPE="swap"`:

```
user@lenovo:~$ cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume
RESUME=UUID=1053a199-0b8f-44ae-9356-c04f5864b138
```

`/etc/default/grub` also could contain option for resume from swap partition:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=/dev/sda5"

sudo update-grub
sudo update-initramfs -c -k $(uname -r)
```

Comment: Right idea. Wrong `resume` file implementation. Only the swap drive should appear in the `resume` file. You also need to search /etc/default/grub for "resume" to make sure it hasn't been added to GRUB.

Comment: @heynnema Ok. Thank you!

Comment: Remember that GRUB line also has this `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`, and the resume should be added to what's there now. Also need to check the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` line. And... followed by a `sudo update-grub` and a `sudo update-initramfs...`.

Comment: That's `sudo update-grub` after the /etc/default/grub changes, and `sudo update-initramfs -c -k $(uname -r)` after the resume file changes (not `-k all` as you don't want/need to update prior files).

Comment: And it looks like their /dev/sda5 is UUID=8cc84133-bb6c-4c98-999c-28315297dacf. And you might use this... `sudo blkid | grep -i swap`.